# How to send data to controller with remote select in Rail 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, html-select

I want to do is load the price of a service. These services are listed in a select tag.

```
<%= f.collection_select(
:service_id,
Service.all,
:id,
:name,
:prompt => 'Select a service') %>

<%= f.label :Price%>
<%= f.number_field :price, :class => 'price-input' %>
```

The idea is that when I select a service, the price appears in the field `:price`.

I have read about `:remote => true` but how can I catch the selected value and send it to the controller? and How can the controller return the response?

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

search for rails unobtrusive javascript

```
<%= f.collection_select(:service_id,Service.all,:id,
:name,:prompt => 'Select a service',
:"data-behavior => "select_service) %>
```

in services.js.coffee ? (assets)

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('[data-behavior="select_service"]').change (e) ->
    $.get '/services/' + this.value + '/select_service',
      (data) ->
        $("#model_price").val(data)
```

the action in your controller (select_service), would get the service and render :text => price

Or something like that.